# yii2:radioList must be a string

Tags: php, yii2

I have this field in my _form.php

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'delivered')->radioList
([ 'delivered' => 'Delivered', 'part' => 'Partly Delivered']) ?>
```

I am getting the error, when I am selecting the radio-box Delivered I am getting the error -

**delivered must be a string**

I can't make out what is wrong in the syntax.

Validation rule in the model is like:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['ipd_patient_id', 'room_name'], 'integer'],
            [['request_time', 'issue_time'], 'safe'],
            [['general_regn_no'], 'string', 'max' => 15],
            [['patient_name'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
            [['delivered'], 'string', 'max' => 20]
        ];
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with your syntax for `radioList`. The only problem is for your validation rules. You have a rule for `delivered` which does not match values (`delivered`,`part`). You need to check your model's rules.

Comment: Thanks Dear Ali - but in model - the validation rule is like - `[['delivered'], 'string', 'max' => 20]` and nothing else. updated the question with model validation rules.

Comment: @Pawan You're welcome dear. That's weird. Somewhere you may put an integer value into `delivered`. Please check all form fields, model's `beforeValidate`

Comment: Yes Dear Ali, You are absolutely right, If I am putting integer, the values is being accepted and saved to DB, but why this is happening, any idea?

Comment: @Pawan how did your problem got solved ???

Comment: @Moeez - you can elaborate on your issue or post a question with a link here, I will sure help.